# Accessing an Outlook Mail's metadata in a Windows Form

Tags: c#, outlook

I need to read Outlook Mails from a Windows Form. It has to be a Windows Form, it cant be an Outlook PlugIn

Basically a person would drag and drop an email(s) from their inbox to a Treeview in my Windows form, where I could extract the data (To, From, CC, Body, Attachments) and store them in an external application.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to notice that to drag an email from Outlook, you will need to select it first. You can then use `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` collection to access the selected messages.

One of the drag/drop formats will be CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR / CF_FILECONTENTS. You can save the data (it is really an MSG file) and then open it using `Application.Session.OpenSharedItem`.

Comment: do you have sample script which does this?

Comment: Accessing the Selection collection? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861267.aspx. Or using the OpenSharedItem method? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869601.aspx